# How to join data from two different database engines (DB2 and SQL Server) in a Java application?

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services, db2

In a Java application we need to join data from 2 databases DB2 and SQL Server using a query statement. I would like to know a good approach to do it.

We need to fetch data from the SQL Server using web service and then join it with data from DB2 using queries within Java code. We need to join the SQL Server's `table` and DB2's `table2`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you will not be able to do this "native" with JDBC. At least once way to do it is at Database leve, you have to create dblinks, I don't know if that can be in DB2 and SQLServer, at least between 2 Oracle Databases you can.

One way to do this programatic would be:

From db2 fill a Map with key as key and the row as value, for example:

```
Map<Integer, Db2RowWrapper> mapDb2 = new HashMap<>();
//fill the map from JDBC , JPA o whatever you use

Map<Integer, SQLServerRowWrapper> sqlServerMap = new HashMap<>();
//Fill it with SQLServer data

//Once you have both maps,
Set<Map.Entry<String, Db2RowWrapper>> rows = mapDb2.entrySet();{

        for(Map.Entry<String, Db2RowWrapper> data : rows) {
            String key = data.getKey();
            //find it in SQL Server map
            SQLServerRowWrapper sqlServerRow = sqlServerMap.get(key);
        }
```

Please consider the memory use and how much records you are using